# Memory overflow! in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, overflow

My embedded system runs Linux 3.10.14.

While running, my application prints out this message.

```
ERR: Memory overflow! free bytes=56000, bytes used=4040000, bytes to allocate=84000
```

But when I do "free", it seems I have enough free memory.

```
/ # free
             total  used  free  shared buffers
Mem:         27652  20788 6864 0            0
-/+ buffers:        20788 6864
Swap:            0            0            0
```

Any possible root cause of the error message?
Or how can I use free memory to the last 1 byte?

Please comment if I am missing any information.
Thank you!

Comment: The kernel will reserve some memory for its uses. If the kernel cant allocate any memory the system will panic, so its essential it has free space. You may be able to tune the amount I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the output of "free", we can see totally there are 27652 bytes, 20788 bytes are used and 6864 bytes are free.

The print from your application, it seems to try to allocate 84000 bytes, but there are only 56000 bytes available。

So there is a question that how much memory do your system have?  27652 bytes or 
4096000 bytes？

The printout is got from the system ？

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Forward. Unit in ERR message is bytes which means my application is requesting ~84KB. And unit in free is KB which means I should have around 6.7MB left. Also as you can see in free output, total memory is 27652KB which is correct number.

Comment: @Seungwhan, so there is a big gap between the command "free" and your application, we suppose "free" is right, is it possible that your application malloc lots of memory about 6864K - 5.6K, at that time there are only 5.6K memory, then you try to malloc 8.4K, so it is failed, and free the memory which has been malloced by your app, then you run the command "free", and see there are totally 6864K?